# Mechanize::ResponseCodeError: 405 => Net::HTTPMethodNotAllowed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-scraping, mechanize

I am trying to fetch the data from an url using mechanize.

But it gives 405 error

```
url = "http://switchboard.com/business?key=habitat%20magazine&where=10001"
agent.get(url)
```

Error:

```
Mechanize::ResponseCodeError: 405 => Net::HTTPMethodNotAllowed for http://switchboard.com/business?key=habitat%20magazine&where=10001 -- unhandled response
```

I am using mechanize agent with proxy. What is the reason for getting this error? I checked the other SO questions but none have answers.